# How to get duplicated medias in Photo Library?

Tags: ios, swift, phphotolibrary

I want to find duplicated photos/videos in photo library and delete them. But I got confused how can I compare all photos to each other and find which of them are duplicated.

Comparing bytes is not useful, which way should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Photos framework you can get a list of all media using the following

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
    if status == .authorized {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending:true)]
        assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
    }
}
```

The code above orders the assets by creation date. That means when checking through your list of 5000 odd assets you only need to check neighboring assets in the list to see if they are duplicates.

Comment: which one code is find duplicate photos ? adamfowlerphoto iLion

Answer (score 2):

You can use below line of code to get properties of media and you can compare metadata with other media files. By this way you can check for duplicate media.

```
let metadata = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: It's ok to compare 2 photos to each other. But how to compare for ex. 5k photos?